# How to use ERC721URIStorage and ERC721Royalty together (requires override)

Tags: solidity, erc-721, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

I am initializing my contract as below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/draft-EIP712.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Royalty.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract NFTMinter is ERC721URIStorage, ERC721Royalty, EIP712, AccessControl
```

And I get 2 errors requiring me to do some overriding. Here is the error:

[image]

I understand `ERC721Storage` and `ERC721Royalty` both have `_burn` with different functionalities but I don't know how to resolve this issue.

`_burn` in ERC721Storage:

```
    /**
     * @dev Destroys `tokenId`.
     * The approval is cleared when the token is burned.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `tokenId` must exist.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     */
    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal virtual override {
        super._burn(tokenId);

        if (bytes(_tokenURIs[tokenId]).length != 0) {
            delete _tokenURIs[tokenId];
        }
    }
```

`_burn` in ERC721Royalty

```
    /**
     * @dev See {ERC721-_burn}. This override additionally clears the royalty information for the token.
     */
    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal virtual override {
        super._burn(tokenId);
        _resetTokenRoyalty(tokenId);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/draft-EIP712.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Royalty.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC721URIStorage, ERC721Royalty, AccessControl {
    constructor() ERC721("MyToken", "MTK") {}


    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }
    
    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721URIStorage, ERC721Royalty) {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721Royalty, AccessControl)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
}
```